# URL prefix "res://" - what does it do or what creates this prefix?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications

I was looking at a url I have discovered in a js file from some website, I'm trying to figure what it's all about and who created the javascript. It is a cookie, that is supposed to block users from downloading content of an XML file more than once (?) per day or visits per unknown time limit.
So starting to investigate the code I can't even remember where exactly I did see this url at first 
it was in a cookie in my temp IE files.

res://mshtml.dll/xmltreeview.js

When trying to google on one of the comments did not yield any result

Comment: [MSDN: res protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) retrieves a custom "XML" resource from a resource module in the "C:\windows\system32 directory.

```
res://C:%5Cwindows%5Csystem32%5Cmsxml3.dll/XML/DEFAULTSS.XSL
```